# VBA: Delete one row if values match

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a macro that looks for **"Total net**" and **"Program Operation net"** in column C. Once located, the macro compares the rows of these two cells and of their values match then row of **"Total Net"** get deleted.

This is my code so far...

```
Sub DeletingEmptyPages()
Dim WS As Worksheet
For Each WS In Sheets

Dim Mystring As String
Dim MystringII As String

MystringII = "Total Net"
Mystring = "Program Operating Net"


  Dim n As Long
  Dim nlast As Long
  Dim rw As Range
  Set rw = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows
  nlast = rw.count
  For n = nlast To 9 Step -1
      If (Column(c).Value = MystringII And Column(c).Value = Mystring) Then
      rw.Rows(n).Delete

      End If
      Next n
      Next WS
      End Sub
```

Comment: `Column` should be `Columns`, and you haven't declared `c` or assigned it a value.  But you won't be able to compare an entire column to your strings anyway.  And if you are trying to just compare the values for a single row for a single column (i.e. a single cell) then that cell's `Value` can't be equal to both `Mystring` **and** `MystringII` at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that when both strings exist in column "C", you want to compare if columns "A" and "B" are equal in both rows. You can use the following code and easily adapt it if more columns need to be compared on the matched rows:

```
Sub Delete_DuplicateTotalNet()

    Dim WS As Worksheet, row1 As Long, row2 As Long
    For Each WS In Sheets
        With WS
            On Error Resume Next
            row1 = WorksheetFunction.Match("Total Net", .Columns("C"), 0)
            row2 = WorksheetFunction.Match("Program Operating Net", .Columns("C"), 0)
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then GoTo NextWS
            If .Range("A" & row1).Value = .Range("A" & row2).Value And _
               .Range("B" & row1).Value = .Range("B" & row2).Value Then
               .Rows(row1).Delete
            End If
        End With
NextWS:
     Err.Clear
     Next WS
End Sub
```

Comment: The issue I was having involved hidden sheets, so `If WS.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then` was added and then it worked

Comment: But is it possible to resize it so it deletes `row1` and everything between `row1` and `row2`. I tried `.Rows(row1).Resize(row2).Delete` it didn't work.

Comment: Or to make it simpler, after `row1` is deleted then everything below `row2` can be deleted.

Comment: Nvm figured it out, it had to be placed after the then.

Comment: A.S.H - I was helping MTBthePRO with another problem, and then we started looking at this one (and **finally** [thanks to what is probably a bug in google sheets] discovered some veryhidden worksheets) but also noticed problems with the error handling in your code.  The first hidden sheet was handled successfully but, because`Err.Clear` clears error information but does not exit out of "error handling" mode, once we hit the second of the hidden sheets the code crashed out.  If you are happy for me to do so, I will edit your answer to include what I believe is correct error handling code.

Comment: @YowE3K Basically `On Error Resume Next` with checking the `Err.Number` afterwards should do, in the original version I tried to make it shorter but true if failed on the second loop if the error occurs again. I edited and this version should work as I tested it, If the problem is not solved plz tell me.

Comment: Yeah - that should be OK - but `Err.Clear` is superfluous because the error information will automatically be cleared once the next `On Error` statement is executed (next time through the loop) or an `Exit Sub` occurs (implicitly at the end of the code).  And, apart from now checking `Err.Number`, the error information isn't actually being used in the code, so there's probably no point in clearing it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This is what it looks like but causes a runtime error

```
    Sub Delete_DuplicateTotalNet()

        Dim WS As Worksheet, row1 As Long, row2 As Long, rng As Long
For Each WS In Sheets
On Error GoTo NextWS

With WS
     If WS.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then

    row1 = WorksheetFunction.Match("Total Net", .Columns(3), 0)
    row2 = WorksheetFunction.Match("Program Operating Net", .Columns(3), 0)
    If .Range("D" & row1).Value = .Range("D" & row2).Value And _
    .Range("E" & row1).Value = .Range("E" & row2).Value And _
    .Range("F" & row1).Value = .Range("F" & row2).Value And _
    .Range("G" & row1).Value = .Range("G" & row2).Value And _
    .Range("H" & row1).Value = .Range("H" & row2).Value And _
    .Range("I" & row1).Value = .Range("I" & row2).Value And _
    .Range("J" & row1).Value = .Range("J" & row2).Value And _
    .Range("K" & row1).Value = .Range("K" & row2).Value Then
    .Rows(row1).Delete
    End If
   End If
   End With
   NextWS:
  Err.Clear
  Next WS

   End Sub
```